# Search group by name in keycloak

Tags: typescript, keycloak

Using `KcAdminClient` and `GroupQuery`, I'm trying to search for a group by its name like this where `keycloak` is my instance of `KcAdminClient`  :

```
const kcQuery = {
  search: groupName,
};
const kcGroups = await this.keycloak.groups.find(kcQuery);
```

`kcGroups` is always empty.
How to search for a group by its name or path ?